# Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected if's waterfall

Tags: c#, .net

I have a problem with my code and says: Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected

```
for (int i = 2001; i<= 2017; i++)
{
     for (int j = 1; j <= 12; j++)
     {
         thursday = LastThursdayOfTheMonth(j, i);

         if (LStock.Any(element => element.date == thursday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", dtf2)))
         {

             line = LStock.First(element => element.date == thursday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", dtf2));
             int index = LStock.IndexOf(line) - 1;
             LFridays.Add(LStock.ElementAt(index));
         }
         else
         {
             while (LStock.Any(element => element.date == thursday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", dtf2)) != true)
             {
                  if (LStock.Any(element => element.date == thursday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", dtf2)))
                  {
                       line = LStock.First(element => element.date == thursday.ToString(("dd-MMM-yyyy"), dtf2));
                       LFridays.Add(line);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     thursday.AddDays(1);
                  }
              }
          }
          else if (thursday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy",dtf2).Contains("25-dic"))
          {
               friday = LastFridayOfTheMonth(j, i);
               bool find = false;
               while (find != true )
               {
                   if (LStock.Any(element => element.date == friday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", dtf2))) 
                   {
                       find = true;
                       line = LStock.First(element => element.date == friday.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy", dtf2));
                       LFridays.Add(line);
                    }                           
                    else
                    {
                        friday = friday.AddDays(1);
                    }
                }

         }
    }
 }
```

I supposed that I have a problem with {} but it's impossible to find where it is. Can someone find if i have less {} or is a different error?

Thank u so much

Comment: Your _else_ block is followed by an _else if_ It should be the reverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are we really supposed to have a

```
if()
{
}
else
{
}
else if()
{
}
```

Shouldn't that be

```
if()
{
}
else if()
{
}
else
{
}
```